# Getting data for 2 different models - Yii2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2

I have a form that inside looks like that:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'comment')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

<?= $form->field($presentation, 'attendance')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($presentation, 'couples')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'hire_price')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

Then I collect received data with controller, like that:

```
$model = new PresentationPlaceHistory();
$presentation = new Presentations();

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save() && $presentation->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $pres = $presentation->findOne($model->presentation_id);
    $pres->attendance = $presentation->load(Yii::$app->request->post('attendance'));
    $pres->couples = $presentation->load(Yii::$app->request->post('couples'));
    $pres->save();
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
else {
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'presentation' => $presentation,
    ]);
}
```

But in the effect, it saves all, beside 'attendance' and 'couples', which are set to 0 (before this form they were null).

It doesn't matter what number I put, I get zero. It doesn't even have to be number, because validation doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following two lines:

```
$pres->attendance = $presentation->load(Yii::$app->request->post('attendance'));
$pres->couples = $presentation->load(Yii::$app->request->post('couples'));

// to this
$pres->attendance = $presentation->attendance;
$pres->couples = $presentation->couples;
```

You have already loaded `$presentation` values here `$presentation->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` and should be available to access directly.

Comment: Wow, that was so simple, and I spent here couple of hours. Now it's far more clear to me, thanks @lenishasda

Comment: I am glad it helped =) @Olga

Answer (score 1):

Kinda messy code u got here. First of all, I suggest you not to use `load()` method, but its my personal preference. [Read more about load](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail).
This method returns `boolean`, that is why you are getting `0` in model properties. In general, your code should look more like:

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
if ($model->save()) {
    $pres = $presentation->findOne($model->presentation_id);

    $pres->attendance = $presentation->attendance;
    //etc ...
    $pres->save()
}
```

I dont know what is the point of your code, but this looks kinda pointless. Try to work with [attributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#$attributes-detail), it is an array of all model properties. Or assign manually wanted properties of the model.

Answer (score 0):

problem with your controller code, change following two lines

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save() && $presentation->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $post_data=  Yii::$app->request->post();

        $pres = $presentation->findOne($model->presentation_id);

        /* change these two lines */
        $pres->attendance = $post_data['Presentations']['attendance'];
        $pres->couples =$post_data['Presentations']['couples'];
        /* change these two lines */

        $pres->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
  } 
  else 
  {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'presentation' => $presentation,
        ]);
  }
```

Comment: Seemed ok, but didn't work for me here. But I didn't know how to access to post data by array, for sure I will use it in another place :)

Comment: can you print model attributes before save, echo "<pre>";print_r($pres->attributes);print_r($post_data)

Comment: I have already found that @leninhasda 's anwer worked here ;)